# How to do this in laravel, Subquery where count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to implement this query in Laravel

```
"SELECT * FROM jobs 
WHERE status = 1 AND 
taskerCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM jobRequests WHERE status = 1 AND job_id = 
jobs.id)"
```

This is what i have tried;

```
Auth::user()->jobs
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->where('taskerCount', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', 1)
              ->where('job_id', $q->id)->count();
        });
```

But I get the error:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to int.

Comment: You can't use ->count on the builder, you can only use it after the statement has been executed. You need to use raw sql to select that as something to be returned with the builder.

Comment: Even though i change it to $q->select(DB::raw('count(*)'))
                    ->where('status', 1)
                    ->where('job_id', $q->id); I still get the same error. And i am not sure about what $q->id returns.

Comment: Check my answer for an example that I have used in the past

Answer (score -2):

Use a raw expression instead of -count().

You can view this [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Example of a raw query from laravel:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                 ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->get();
```

Make sure you define the count as a name.